# Time complexity for listing directories and subdirectories

Tags: python-3.x, directory, time-complexity, pathlib

I used something like this to go through all subdirectories in every directory for `.txt` files:

```py
for txt_file in pathlib.Path(path).glob('**\*.txt'): ...
```

But I'm not sure how to determine worst time complexity for it.

Comment: This depends on how the file system handles meta-data and lookups. It won't be correctly answerable in general.

Comment: Time complexity as a function of what variable?